# AngularJS ui-grid edit button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

[image: editable fields]

In the given picture each cell is editable using ui-grid-edit.After editing of cell. It will call the webservices.

I am trying to have an edit button where the user can click and enable edit functionality and also would be able to edit the whole row. So all the row data will go once to web service(not only one cell).

For example:- In the present scenario, If I edit Broad Frequency, It will call the web service.

Now, I want to have an  edit button where the user can click edit then will be able to edit all the cells and after editing all the cells.

Here is the tutorial link which I used for this:-

[ui-grid tutorial link](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable)

Comment: see this [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/VO6F3vlOOwaudfi3RSVA/)

Comment: this is not working properly I guess. Showing same thing